# VirtualProtect Size

Tags: c++, pointers, hook

So i was playing around with function hooking on Windows and everything was pretty much working as expected. By overriding the value my LoadLibrary Pointer points to with a jmp instruction and the offset to my Hook Function, i am able to execute my own Code on every call to LoadLibrary. To override the bytes in memory i obviously need to change the protection flags for the specific memory. Even though this works fine i got an unexpected result.

```
HMODULE APIENTRY hLoadLibrary(LPCWSTR lpFileName) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "NOT LOADING A LIBRA1RY!", "YO", MB_OK);

    return NULL;
};

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD  fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    DWORD* hookPointer = (DWORD*)&hLoadLibrary;
    DWORD* originPointer = (DWORD*)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW");

    DWORD offset = (DWORD)hookPointer - (DWORD)originPointer - 5;

    DWORD oldProtect;
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)originPointer, sizeof(char) * 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);

    char* p = (char*)originPointer;
    *p = '\xE9';
    p++;
    DWORD* q = (DWORD*)p;
    *q = offset;

    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)originPointer, sizeof(char) * 5, oldProtect, &oldProtect);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Where this

```
VirtualProtect((LPVOID)originPointer, sizeof(char) * 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
```

is what i expected to work

This

```
VirtualProtect((LPVOID)originPointer, 0, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
```

obviously failing

But this

```
VirtualProtect((LPVOID)originPointer, 1, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
```

i found to also work, even though i only change the Protection for one byte.

Can someone explain why this works?

Comment: Do you expected 5-byte protection change operation to succeed, but 1-byte to fail? Why? If it works for 5-bytes, it will most likely work for 1-byte. Refer to documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You never check result of `VirtualProtect` to check whether it fails or not and never call `GetLastError` to check failure reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page protection attributes necessarily have a granularity equal to the size of a page.  4096 bytes.  You should never lie about the size you need, bummer if the address you pass happens to be located near the end of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just checked msdn again and it looks like i stopped reading after "The size of the region whose access protection attributes are to be changed, in bytes." So this would mean if the size i specify also includes the next page, the protection attributes would be set for both of those pages?

Comment: Yes, necessarily so.  The api strongly avoids making assumptions about page size and valid protection attributes, they are a processor implementation detail.

Comment: From wikipedia *The available page sizes depend on the instruction set architecture, processor type, and operating (addressing) mode. The operating system selects one or more sizes from the sizes supported by the architecture.*  So, it's up to the OS to choose one of the supported page sizes.